# Possible to skip plotting a data point in a line chart?

Tags: dimple.js

We are missing data for some months. If no lines have the month then it just doesn't show up. If one line has it but another doesn't then it seems to sort that month before all the others which looks strange. So we've added in place holder data with a value of zero for missing months but we'd prefer it not actually plot those points.

Ideally, we'd like for all 12 months to show up in the x axis but if a data point is missing (or zero; whatever would make this easier) then we don't want that point to be plotted.

Is dimple able to do this natively, or would I need to manually remove the point with javascript after the chart has been drawn? And if the latter is the case, any pointers to get me started on how to do that would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're missing a lot of data I would just do a scatter plot and then plotly has the ability to connect the dots, so to speak.

Comment: @DevinBurke We're only missing one point of data for the month of April actually. The problem is that we're showing year over year line charts, and we seem to be stuck with one of two undesirable conditions. 1) We omit the data for April 2020, and dimple orders the month of April of 2019 to the very left of the x axis in spite of the order rule. 2) We provide a value of 0 for the missing month of April and it skews the line chart (i.e. compressing the rest of the line because it goes so far down to hit zero).

Comment: @DevinBurke And ideally my hope is that we receive this data... I'm not even entirely sure why we don't have it at the moment, whether it was due to COVID issues and whether or not we are even legitimately missing data (i.e. was the data is pushed out into the adjacent months?). So in short, we're not missing a lot of data. And the types of charts I have to produce are pretty much set in stone... that is, I am not in a position to say "well, why don't we try this type of chart instead of that".